# Image not uploading in spring mvc

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I'am developing a Spring MVC Application.
In it am uploading a image to `WEB-INF\resources\imgages folder` , but image is not adding to the folder.

[image]

In console it is showing

> Multipart file 'imageFile' with original filename [Penguins.jpg],
>   stored at
>   [D:\Clickindians_Web.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Click-Indians\upload__3b6778cf_156c1787f2b__7ffd_00000012.tmp]:
>   moved to
>   [D:\Clickindians_Web.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Click_Indians\WEB-INF\resources\images\Penguins.jpg]

My code is:

```
@RequestPart(value = "imageFile", required = false) MultipartFile file,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

     if (!file.isEmpty()) {
         try {

             String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        path= Paths.get(rootDirectory+"\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\");


             String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
             String filePath = path + "\\"+orgName;
             File dest = new File(filePath);
             file.transferTo(dest);
         }catch(Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Product Image saved failed",ex);

        }
     }
```

I want to Host this app in real time Server..

Comment: [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) is an execellent example of how to upload files in Spring.

Comment: Why would you save images there? You will lose them next time you deploy your app. Neither does your attached image prove anything. You need to refresh the folder in Eclipse if files have been added outside of the IDE.

Comment: Then how to store images outside of my app ,can you give one working example code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example on how I do it with Spring. It's Groovy but easily convertible to Java by just declaring the variables to their types.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
def upload(@ModelAttribute("file") MultipartFile file) {
    def fullPath = "/some/path/" + file.originalFilename

    def outputFile = new File(fullPath)
    outputFile.mkdirs()

    def bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.bytes)
    def original = ImageIO.read(bis)
    ImageIO.write(original, "PNG", outputFile)
}
```

Comment: Using ur code I can upload image into my local drive but it is not working for uploading image into webapp folder.

Comment: Of course, as Alan Hay mentioned, it's a terrible idea. You will lose that folder on your next deployment. You should pick a folder outside the whole deployment environment.

Comment: Hi Trojahn Can you give a example code to store images outside of Myapp.